# Measurement on density operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, measurement-problem, density-operator, trace

Question:

> A system in a mixed state $\rho$ is measured with the measurement described by a projection operator $P$.
>
> 1. What is the probability of the outcome?
> 2. What is the density operator of the system after a measurement?
> 3. State and explain whether $\rho$ is necessarily still in a mixed state after the measurement.

I have checked many textbooks, and basically all of them only discuss the the expectation value $\langle A \rangle =Tr(\rho A)$. What about the actual state after measurement? In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Measurement) it says $\rho'=P\rho P$, but how to justify this expression? For (3), I only get
$$Tr(\rho'^2)=Tr(P\rho PP\rho P)=Tr(P\rho P\rho P)=Tr(P\rho P\rho)=Tr(P\rho P\rho),$$
but then I don't know how to proceed. Any idea?

Comment: What exactly is $P$ here? is it a projector?

Comment: Yes, $P$ is a projector

Comment: Please see section 2.5 of [this note](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/quantum15/lecture16.pdf). In particular, the answer by @ZeroTheHero is wrong! And the wikipedia entry has been corrected to $\rho_i' = \frac{P_i \rho P_i}{\operatorname{tr}[\rho P_i]}$, if the measurement outcome is $i$.

Comment: @taper Maybe I'm misunderstanding something in your comment as my answer collapses to the expression $\vert\psi^\prime_j\rangle:= \frac{M_i\vert\psi_j\rangle}{\sqrt{p_{ji}}}$ for a pure state given in the section you refer to.  Indeed the projector $P$ is written in those notes as $M_i^\dagger M_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a measurement, the system should be in the eigenstate of $\hat A$ 
with eigenvalue $a_i$ (assuming no degeneracy in the spectrum) since you know the outcome was $a_i$.  Normally, the measurement does not preserve the norm so physically you know that your density matrix after the measurement should be
$$
\hat \rho' \propto \vert a_i\rangle\langle a_i\vert\, .
$$ 
where $\vert a_i\rangle$ is the eigenvector of $\hat A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $a_i$.

Now, start with the projector $P$ and the density matrix $\rho$ written
explicitly as 
\begin{align}
P&=\vert a_i\rangle\langle a_i\vert \, ,\\
\hat \rho &= \sum_j p_j \vert \psi_j\rangle \langle \psi_j\vert
\end{align}
and examine $P\hat \rho P$.  Inserting the expressions yields explicitly
\begin{align}
\hat \rho'&= \sum_j p_j  \vert a_i\rangle\langle a_i\vert \psi_j\rangle \langle \psi_j \vert a_i\rangle\langle a_i\vert \\
&= \vert a_i\rangle\langle a_i\vert \left(\sum_j p_j \vert \langle a_i\vert \psi_j\rangle\vert^2\right)\, ,\\
&=\vert a_i\rangle \langle a_i\vert \beta_i\, , \qquad \beta_i> 0
\end{align}
which is what you expect.  Of course, as mentioned above, $\hat \rho'$ is no longer normalized - but that's to be expected because projectors are no norm-preserving operators.

In this example where there is no degeneracy, $\hat \rho'$ is a pure state.  You can scratch your head as to whether or not this remains true if the eigenvalue $a_i$ occurs multiple times in the spectrum and, in particular, if this degeneracy changes the projector $P$.